# Randomizing quiz-answers fetched from a rest-API

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

So I've created a quiz-app that fetches 10 random questions with three incorrect and one correct answer to choose from. Everything is working great at the moment except that I can't get the answers to pop up randomly. And by that I mean that the correct answer is always at the bottom of the choices presented.

I know that the answer is Math.floor(Math.random() * ... ) but I honestly have no idea where to put it. I've tried everything. I could really use some help.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const API =
  "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=20&difficulty=medium";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      score: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateAppWithData();
  }

  populateAppWithData() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results }))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

  render() {
    const { results } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Quiz App</h1>
        <TheCounter results={results}
          Counter={this.state.score}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class MythologyAnswers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answered: "",
      isRight: null,
    };
  }
  answerClicked(answer) {
    const { hasAnswered, correct_answer } = this.props;
    return event => {
      const isRight = correct_answer === answer;
      hasAnswered(isRight);
      this.setState({
        answered: answer,
        isRight,
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers } = this.props;
    const { answered, isRight } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="allAnswers">
        {question}
        {incorrect_answers && incorrect_answers
          .concat(correct_answer)
          .map(answer => (<div onClick={this.answerClicked(answer)}>{answer} </div>))}<br />
        {answered && `You answered ${answered}`} {" "} <br />
        <div className="correctAnswer"> {" "}{answered && isRight && "This is correct!"} </div> <br />
        <div className="incorrectAnswer"> {" "}{answered && !isRight && `This is incorrect. The correct answer is ${this.props.correct_answer}`} {" "}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class TheCounter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      right: 0,
      Counter: 0,
      unanswered: 0,
    };
  }
  questionAnswered = isRight => {
    this.setState(({ Counter, right }) => ({
      Counter: Counter + 1,
      right: right + isRight,
    }));
  }
  render() {
    const { results } = this.props;
    const { Counter } = this.state;
    const unanswered = this.props.results && Counter;
    if (unanswered >= 10) {
      return <div className="theUnanswered"> You got {this.state.right} right out of {this.state.Counter} </div>;
    }
    const question = results[Counter];
    return (
      <div className="newQuestion">
        <MythologyAnswers {...question} hasAnswered={this.questionAnswered} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Vicky, I just provided you a solution on how you can randomize your array without Knufes algorithm. It should also make your mark-up cleaner :)

Comment: Hi @ChristopherNgo many thanks for your help and your code. I know my code isn't very clean at the moment but in order to keep learning and not get too confused at the moment I'd prefer to stay with the code that I already have. If it's not too much to ask could you perhaps show me what I can do with what I already have to achieve the random function? When I first started I had all the code in one component and I was able to randomize simply by adding math.floor(math.random()) when calling the results-state in return but ever since I split it in three I have no clue where to do that.

Comment: let me take a look and see if I can mod my answer to use your existing code. In the mean time, can you try my answer below and see if it works?

Comment: Hi Vicky, any luck on integrating the below? I'm still reworking the code so that it doesnt look too different from what you wrote.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherNgo. I'm so sorry for the late reply. I just tried the code you provided earlier and it works really well and it randomizes my answers as I wanted it to.

Comment: Vicky thats awesome! I'll update my answer right now with how you could do this with your original code, hopefully it still looks familiar.

Comment: Vicky, cool see my updated answer, towards the end! It has a small variation of your code.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo OMG You are brilliant!! I just implemented the new code and thank you so much for the explanations as well that really helped me understand the entire code in general. Thank you so so so much!!

Comment: you're very welcome! I'm glad I was able to help you resolve this interesting problem! Let me know if you have any questions as well! Please consider marking my solution as the answer. :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I just did. One last question. Every time I'm getting the answer incorrect the text below shows the answer of the upcoming question. Do you have any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Vicky, hmm I'm not entirely sure. I would guess that it has something to do with this line:         `{answered &&
            !isRight &&
            This is incorrect. The correct answer is ${
              this.props.correct_answer
            }}`  what are you passing in as a prop called correct_answer from the component that uses MythologyAnswers?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo aghh!! of course!! I just removed the this.props.correct_answer and replaced it with answered and it is working as it should now. Many thanks again!

Comment: Awesome Vicky!!! Have a wonderful weekend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to apply the randomizer in the right place. You use `.concat()` to combine the two arrays, so it makes sense to use the randomizer right after that and before we call `.map()`

I've set up something that preserves alot of the existing logic you already wrote.

This will help create the new Arr and set-up the markup for your component.

```
  renderChoices = () => {
    const { correct_answer, incorrect_answers } = this.props;

    let allAnswers = incorrect_answers
      ? incorrect_answers.concat(correct_answer)
      : [];

    //simple shuffle algorithm. Just inject your array and it'll pop out a new one.

    function createRandom(arr) {
       let myArr = [...arr];  //copy arr we pass in
       let randomizedArr = []; //gets popuated by loop

       while (myArr.length > 0) {
          var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArr.length); //create random number
          randomizedArr.push(myArr[randomIndex]); //add choice randomly to arr
          myArr.splice(randomIndex, 1); //cut out a piece of the array then resart loop
      }
       //when loop has finished, return random array
       return randomizedArr;
    }

    //call randomizer and get new Arr
    let randomizedArr = createRandom(allAnswers); 

    //use .map to create markup with randomizedArr
    return randomizedArr.map(answer => {
      return <div onClick={this.answerClicked(answer)}>{answer}</div>;
    });
  };
```

So if you were to call the above function inside `render`, it will create the answer-set for you.

```
  render() {
    const { question } = this.props;
    const { answered, isRight } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="allAnswers">

        {question}

        { this.renderChoices()}

        <br />

        {answered && `You answered ${answered}`} <br />

        <div className="correctAnswer">
          {answered && isRight && "This is correct!"}
        </div>

        <br />

        <div className="incorrectAnswer">
          {answered &&
            !isRight &&
            `This is incorrect. The correct answer is ${
              this.props.correct_answer
            }`}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Clean and not too-complex :)

**Edit: so without changing your original code too much:**

```
  createRandom(arr) {
    let myArr = [...arr]; //copy arr we pass in
    let randomizedArr = []; //gets popuated by loop

    while (myArr.length > 0) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArr.length); //create random number
      randomizedArr.push(myArr[randomIndex]); //add choice randomly to arr
      myArr.splice(randomIndex, 1); //cut out a piece of the array then resart loop
    }
    //when loop has finished, return random array
    return randomizedArr;
  }

  render() {
    const { question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers } = this.props;
    const { answered, isRight } = this.state;
    const allAnswers =
      incorrect_answers ? incorrect_answers.concat(correct_answer) : [];
    const randomizedAnswers = this.createRandom(allAnswers)

    return (
      <div className="allAnswers">
        {question}
        {randomizedAnswers
            .map(answer => (
              <div onClick={this.answerClicked(answer)}>{answer} </div>
            ))}
        <br />
        {answered && `You answered ${answered}`} <br />
        <div className="correctAnswer">
          {answered && isRight && "This is correct!"}
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="incorrectAnswer">

          {answered &&
            !isRight &&
            `This is incorrect. The correct answer is ${
              this.props.correct_answer
            }`}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So in the edited version we do a couple things:

1. Defined a function called `createRandom()` ... all it does is
   randomize your answers choices.
2. In `render`, we created a new variable called allAnswers which just
   `concat()` the `incorrect_answers` and `correct_answer` like you did
   previously. If there are no `incorrect_answers` defined, we will use
   an empty array [] as the default value.
3. Create a new variable called `randomizedAnswers`. We call
   `createRandom()` and pass in `allAnswers` as the argument. It returns
   the randomized array for us to use.
4. Then just `.map()` over `randomizedAnswers` to create your
   answer-choices markup.

Answer (score 1):

In below code , I suppose you are trying to concat incorrect_answer array with the correct_answer

```
incorrect_answers && incorrect_answers
          .concat(correct_answer)
```

so array becomes `[incorrect_answers,incorrect_answers,incorrect_answers,correct_answer]`
i.e correct answer is at end
so if you want to insert correct answer at random position and suppose there are 4 options then first generate a random number between 0 and 3

```
let randonIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
```

then insert correct answer at random index

```
incorrect_answers && incorrect_answers
          .splice(randomIndex, 0, correct_answer);
```

Comment: Hi @Akash. Thank you so much for the reply. When I replace .concat(correct_answer) with .splice(... ) the answers all disappear from the screen and I only get the actual question and when clicking on it nothing happens either

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally add it right after fetching the data. Using an inline shuffle like Fisher-Yales you don't need to modifiy your structure at all.

```
const fisherYalesShuffle = (a) => {
    let j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
}
```

However, since you generally want to move as much data-logic as possible to your backend, you should also consider shuffling them there instead.

Comment: Hi @Berouminum. Thank you for your reply. I tried as you wrote and nothing happened. and I'm not att all familiar with Fisher-Yales so I'd prefer at the moment a clue that I can understand (I still consider myself a newbie when it comes to react) as for the 2nd suggestion as I wrote before I have at the moment no clue on where to put that code at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a shuffle function (This one is Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) shuffle):

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

And then just apply the function when setting the state like this:

`this.setState({ results: this.shuffle(data.results) })`

Comment: Hi @Sergio. Thank you very much but as I said before I think this is a bit too complex for me at the moment. I would really appreciate something a bit easier. But many thanks!

Comment: Well the only easier option that I can think of could be using lodash shuffle (https://lodash.com/docs/#shuffle)
just install lodash, import it like 
`import _ from 'lodash'`
and do
```this.setState({ results: _.shuffle(data.results) }))```